Relation between Hessian of the squared distance function and the metric tensor
Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and let $d$ be the distance function associated with the metric tensor $g$. Define the function $$ f(x) := \frac12 d^2 (x,y) $$ for some arbitrary fixed $y \in M$.
Is the second derivative of the function $f$ at $x$ the same as the metric tensor at $x$? That is, can we say
$$ D^2 f (x) (u,v) = g_x(u,v) $$
for all $u,v \in T_xM$? Clearly it holds for the Euclidean manifold, and also for a manifold where one defines $g_A(u,v) := \langle u, A v \rangle$ for a positive definite matrix $A$.
I'm aware that one can get the metric tensor from the distance function if one sets $x,y$ to be infinitesimally close (by definition), but does the same hold for arbitrary points on the manifold?
If it does not hold for all Riemannian manifolds, what are the minimum conditions one must place on the manifold so that it holds?
